# React Native navigation actions

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have problem about navigation from other script (screen)... I implemented navigation in App.js (with `createStackNavigator` and with screens). Everything works fine when I want to navigate (with `OnPress{() => navigate("someScreen")}` to  screen which is defined in this script (App.js).

But, when I want to use that navigation from other script (outside of App.js), let's say in "NewPage.js"
which has own "`export default class NewPage`..." and inside I have button element which task is to navigate "`onPress`" to screen which is defined in the App.js `stackNavigator`...

I know that I can't use anymore `navigate("pageName")` because navigation isn't implemented in this script and I tried with `import { NavigationActions } from 'react-native'` and inside of button element I tried with code: "`this.props.navigation.navigate('somePage')`" and it's not working.

So I don't know how to use navigation property from other script in which isn't implemented navigation, how to reference/export/import that property?

Here is code App.js script: https://pastebin.com/tLEFdQrE and NewPage.js script: https://pastebin.com/aVQGiinJ

This code is short so you can easily see what I want and what is the problem...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this for better navigation among screen as compared to default navigation this is the better one for navigating among the screens. We mostly use this than other navigator

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: Thank you Tale! I used this package and it works :) 
Also I used this tutorial to see the whole idea of this package: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc5d4EIBJb4

I hope this will be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You should import your pages [using the names of the exported components, not the names of the js files] into your App.js.

For example, I stored my pages in a folder called 'screens' so when I imported my 'Home' screen, I used

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen.js';
```

which was further referenced as

```
Home: HomeScreen,
```

Good luck!

Comment: Reachel, how then I can navigate from page in which I imported "homScreen" like you said with "full reference"? I tried with "this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')" and I still can't...